# R C symbol name "do_is_ordered" not in the DLL for package xts

Tags: r, dll, installation, xts

I have R installed on my computer in the office and I have experienced something weird. I was trying to use the xts package but the following is happening:

```
library(xts)
data(sample_matrix) 
sample.xts <- as.xts(sample_matrix, descr='my new xts object')
Fehler in .Call("do_is_ordered", x = x, increasing = as.logical(increasing),  :
C Symbolname "do_is_ordered" nicht in der DLL für Paket "xts"
```

I am sorry for the German text but I did not find the equivalent in English, the statement is saying something like  C symbol name "do_is_ordered" is not in the DLL for package "xts".

Here is my session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.13.2 (2011-09-30)
Platform: i386-pc-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Austria.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Austria.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=German_Austria.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=German_Austria.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] PerformanceAnalytics_1.0.3.2 xlsReadWrite_1.5.4
[3] quantmod_0.3-15              TTR_0.20-2
[5] Defaults_1.1-1               xts_0.7-5
[7] zoo_1.6-4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_2.13.2     lattice_0.19-33 tools_2.13.2
```

As I have mentioned before, it is a computer in the office which has restricted access to the internet, all the packages are installed from the local folder and I can not simply reinstall the version of R as I would wish the most. It is weird as other computers in the office dont produce any errors with the same code. I would like to ask you what could produce the error (wrong installation?) resp. how could I fix it without necessity of reinstalling R (which is not as simply as one would expect, especially with the IT service behind my back :-))

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the packages `zoo`, `quantmod` and `xts`? Presumably you don't need IT support for that...

Comment: Do the other computers in the office have the exact same `sessionInfo` (especially R version, package versions)?  How were the packages you installed built (i.e. are they binaries from CRAN/R-forge, did someone build them from source, etc.)?

Comment: The installation process is exercised as following- every three months, the IT department downloads current R version and corresponding packages and install it on the computers- so to @Joshua- yes, other computers have the same R version, package versions. I have experienced something more weird today. I was working on one code yesterday (which run without any problem), but the same code didnt work today at all. It was simple volatility function from the TTR package so I have tried tu use some other functions when I realized I can not use them at all. For example

Comment: data(ttrc)                                                                 
# Bollinger Bands
bbands <- BBands( ttrc[,c("High","Low","Close")] )
Fehler in .Fortran("runsum", ia = as.double(x[beg:NROW(x)]), lia =
as.integer(len),  :
 Fortran Symbolname "runsum" nicht in der DLL für Paket "TTR"                                                                
which is simimal problem but with the DLL for TTR. We are going to install the latest version of R on my computer so I hope the problem will be solved, hovewer I am very curious what might be a reason for those statements.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error and refer to [Xts conversion fails on update from xts 0.9.7 to 0.10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732011/xts-conversion-fails-on-update-from-xts-0-9-7-to-0-10-0), reinstalled [`devtools::install_github("joshuaulrich/xts")`](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/xts) is work for me.